# Create a cookie for a button and disable it after 10 minutes

Tags: jquery, button, cookies, timer, disabled-input

So I am having this page where I have a main button that takes you to an other page within the website.
So we have "/" and "/game". Once you are in /game there's an other button with id #quest1. Once someone clicks that button, a timer is set for the main button (a.PlayNow) to turn red for 10 minutes.
The problem is my code never changes.
I made this work, but the button doesn't turn back to it's normal form even after 10 minutes have passed. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
  var last = my_getcookie('lastClicked');
  var current = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);

  $('#quest1').click(function(){
    my_setcookie('lastClicked', current ,1,0);
  });

  if( last + 600 < current ) {
    // 10 minutes over
    $('a.PlayNow').attr('href','/game').css({'background':'#a7822f','cursor':'pointer'});
    $('a.PlayNow').text('Play Crossroadz!');
  } else {
    // 10 minutes not over
    $('a.PlayNow').removeAttr('href').css({'background':'#b34c4c','cursor':'not-allowed'});
    $('a.PlayNow').text('Time not passed!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve that by using a timer... Just call `buttonPressed()` when someone clicked your button.

```
var timer;

function buttonPressed()
{
    // make button red

    timer = setInterval(restoreButton, 1000 * 60 * 10);
}

function restoreButton()
{
    // make button normal again
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: So I only use `$('#quest1').click(function(){buttonPressed();});` and it's done? (OFC add the changes to the button)

Comment: Yep and of course implement the code for makin the button red and normal again.

Comment: `$('#quest1').click(function(){
    buttonPressed();
  });

var timer;

function buttonPressed()
{
    // make button red
    $('a.PlayNow').removeAttr('href').css({background:'#b34c4c',cursor:'not-allowed'});
    $('a.PlayNow').text('Time not passed!');
    timer = setInterval(restoreButton, 1000 * 60 * 10);
}

function restoreButton()
{
    // make button normal again
    $('a.PlayNow').attr('href','/game').css({background:'#a7822f',cursor:'pointer'});
    $('a.PlayNow').text('Play Crossroadz!');
    clearInterval(timer);
}`

Comment: are the two buttons on diffrent pages?

Comment: I thought they were on the same? how can one be on two pages at the same time? what's the usecase?

Comment: I am trying to make a game where as soon as you press the button to start the game, you'll not be able to start an other game while the time span has not passed. That's the purpose of this.. That's why I used cookies in the first place.

Comment: Okay, then try setting the expiration time of the cookie to +10min and just check wheter it's still there when the main button is clicked.

Comment: I have the `if( last + 600 < current )` to check if the 10 minutes have passed but idk why but this never turns true..

Comment: You actually have to run that code repeatedly, of course it never returns true if you just run it once. So use setInterval() to check repeatedly every few seconds or so.

Comment: Also, in the above code every time you press that main button, it extends that time span to another 10 minutes. the cookie creation should only be executed outside that timespan.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to use that type of function.. :(

Comment: The main button (a.PlayNow) is disabled once the Play button (#quest1) is pressed..

Comment: (1). I won't do your homework. So if you don't know that function, look up the reference. (2). I just posted an example how to use that function as an answer to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'll think of an other way to do this.. Sorry for your time.. (And this is no homework. It's just a game I'm trying to create.)
Anyway, thanks for your help @alex_ulmer

Comment: Also setInterval() will not work because as soon as the window is closed this will stop. So it's like I'm giving my users a solution of how to avoid waiting the time span to pass..

Comment: No this just checks repeadedly whether the cookie still exists! And if they close the site and then reopen it, it will still be checking wheter the cookie exists or not.

Comment: So all i have to do is add `setInterval('lastClicked', 1000 * 60 * 10);` under the setcookie part and then a `clearInterval('lastClicked');` in the section of the "over" time? I'm confused..

Comment: Ok. You want to check every few seconds whether your cookie exists. Why don't you just look up the reference for setInterval() and then come up with a solution for this problem by applying the knowledge?

Comment: This is what I get when I look it up: _**The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.**_